# I would like to ask about EEA permit

Tags: uk-visa

I would like to ask about EEA permit. I am holding a Indian passport and married to EU national. this aug 2019 my 2 years visit visa got refused. Can I still apply for EEA permit in Dubai? like to ask you what I can do next? As my Kids (EU national) want to study in the UK

Comment: According to https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eea-family-permit you must apply as an extended family member if you’re not the spouse/ civil partner or dependent child to an EEA national student and want a family permit. Extended family members are not guaranteed to get a permit. What was the reason for the visa refusal?

Comment: Are you planning to travel to the UK with your EU citizen spouse?  Are you hoping to live with your kids in the UK while they are studying there, or just to visit them from time to time?

Comment: I am planning to live in UK, while my kids are studying